# jQuery селектор

Tags: jquery

Ищу элемент с помощью селектора:

```
$(this).children().next().next().next().next().find('input').val();
```

Все работает корректно.

Но мне сильно не нравиться такая запись, наверняка есть способ написать это короче?

Comment: Да, наверняка есть.

Comment: Добавьте html, в котором вы ищете input

Comment: Это таблица с динамически меняющимся количеством строк. В каждой строке определенное количество столбцов, в каждой строке мне надо найти определенный инпут.

Comment: @Евгений_20171004, добавьте сюда пример таблицы. Мы должны видеть HTML, чтобы помочь вам

Comment: Без разметки  и четкого условия решаемой задачи - помочь ничем нельзя, кроме как посоветовать то, что написано в ответе

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте вашему `input` или `class` или же `id` после чего сможете получать данные более менее нормально, например так

HTML

```
<input class="myInput" type="text" value="" />
```

JS

```
$('.myInput').val();
```